# Where is my 7za data being written to

Tags: centos, files, zip, compression

I have a weird question about 7za on Centos 7. I am adding a file to a 7za archive using the following command (the total size of the directory is around 40GB)

```
/usr/bin/7za a -ppassword -t7z -mmt=off -m0=deflate -mx=1 /home/archive.zip /home/Directory/
```

As this is going on, I check the size of /home/archive.zip and its 0:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Apr 29 13:01 /home/archive.zip
```

However when using fuser and lsof to find out what this PID is doing, I can see it has /home/archive.zip open for writing: "3w" FD. And I can see the individual files being processed.

My question is: where is it writing this data as it is archiving? Why is my new file 0 bytes?

If its a temp file its writing to, why does the 7za PID have /home/archive.zip open for writing.

Basically -- where is this data going?

Comment: try running the same command prepended with `strace` on it

Comment: @JacobMinshall I appended strace to the running process and it shows nothing writing. Here is what I used: strace -e trace=write

Comment: Try this strace: `strace -f -v -s150 -o log`. Analyze, and possibly post result `log` file.